# Onclick button to disappear and show hidden fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

So basically, i'm trying to make a button "Call me back" so when you click it, it disappears and shows other two hiddens fields.

http://investinlisbon.ml/

What im trying to change is that little form on top of that page where it has 2 fields and a call me back button.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, only got the form done. I'm very new to web design, still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 0):

try jquery show / hide functions like

```
$("#div_to_show").show(); 
$("#div_to_hide").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should approach your problem:

**HTML**

`<div id="div1"> </div>`

`<div id="div2" style="display:none"> </div>`

`<div id="div3" style="display:none"> </div>`

**JS**

`document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";`
`document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "inline-block";`
`document.getElementById("div3").style.display = "inline-block";`

Answer (score 0):

Another one, one liner:

HTML

```
<div id="fields" style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Telephonoe"/>
</div>
<button type="button" id="contact-btn" onClick="toggleFields()">
Contact me
</button>
```

JS

```
 function toggleFields(){
    $('#fields, #contact-btn').toggle();
 }
```

Example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsauxfu6/8/)

Comment: That's exactly what i want. but i forgot to mention, i'm working with Contact Form 7 so instead of those fields, i need to call the form i created wich aldready has the fields in php

Comment: @PedroBronze not sure what you mean by your comment, above is just an example, do what you must.

Comment: @PedroBronze You cannot use my code as is, of course; also, add script after jQuery (which is loaded in the end of page in your case), switch your form on your site back to original, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

in your **View**

```
    <div style="display: none;" class="hideDiv">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="1101">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.4">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="pt_PT">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f1101-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="7b5f59556f">
</div>
```

and **jquery**

```
$(document).on('click','.send-cmb',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hideDiv').css('display:block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**html code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>   
<input type="text" name="text-574" value="" size="40" class="txt" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="text-574" value="" size="40" class="txt" placeholder="Telephone">
        <button type="button" id="callback" >
Call Back
</button>
```

**js code**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

 jQuery(".txt").hide();
    jQuery("#callback").click(function(){
    jQuery(".txt").show();
    jQuery("#callback").hide();

    });
});
```

You can view [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/5vme2tta/1/)